# Tycho jenkins build fail - nullpointer

Tags: eclipse-plugin, jenkins, tycho

I have problems with Tycho build on Jenkins. On my local machine i have success build.

I have two projects p2 and apll. In p2 I simply repack artifacts to eclipse-plugins with well formated manifest, pom etc. This build is ok.

Apll build fails when is about to start compiling plug-ins. When I point Jenkins directly on my plugin pom, I have success build. But when I start from parent pom it fails. My project structure:

```
-root
  |-core
    |-plugin1
    |-plugin1junit
    |-plugin2
    |-plugin2junit
    |-core-feature
  |-lib-feature
    |-nattable-feature
    |-chart-feature
  |-product
```

root - pom with tycho plugin and target platform conf, dependencys to p2 plugin //package pom

core pom

lib-feature - features from p2 plugins

product - materialization

```
build result:
root - SUCCESS 
Core - SUCCESS
p2-feature - SUCCESS
nattable-feature - SUCCESS
chart-feature - SUCCESS
plugin1 - FAILURE 
... - FAILURE
```

and stack:

```
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.BuilderCommon.handleBuildError(BuilderCommon.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:95)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:158)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:122)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:74)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener.recordProjectStarted(Maven3Builder.java:368)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener.projectStarted(Maven3Builder.java:358)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:71)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:42)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:78)
    ... 24 more
```

---

Tom

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in Tycho 0.14.0-SNAPSHOT that was [fixed](http://git.eclipse.org/c/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho.git/commit/?id=5e3be8b5149fd71f1691b6fc213b877b3153a94a) a while ago already.
Are you by any chance still using an outdated Tycho 0.14.0-SNAPSHOT version?

Neither Tycho 0.13.0 nor Tycho 0.14.1 should have this problem.

Comment: I'm using 0.13.0, 0.14.1 have problems with optional imports in manifest. I set up Jenkins to execute shell script and my build was success.

Answer (score 0):

The Maven job type in Jenkins had been giving NPEs, but this has been fixed in a recent Jenkins update, so try updating your Jenkins to see if it resolves.